# fillna is not able to replace null values with a given date value for a DateType field

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark

I have created a dataframe as below: -

[image]

Schema of the given dataframe as below: -
[image]

I wanted to replace null values in DateType field "customer_from". But the below query is not working

```
df.na.fill({"customer_from":date.now()}).show()
```

Where as na.fill is working for other type columns like "amount_type" i.e. a DoubleType column.

Why na.fill is not working for DateType columns but working for other column types in spark ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the [API Reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions.fill.html) it's said that `na.fill` only accepts int, float, boolean and string as replacement types.

[image: API Reference]

I don't know why it doesn't accept other types, but you can use the [`when`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.when.html) function instead:

```
df.withColumn('customer_from',
  F.when(F.expr('customer_from IS NULL'), DEFAULT_DATE).otherwise(F.col('customer_from')))
```

Being `DEFAULT_DATE` the date you want to use to replace null values.

Comment: I understand this is a work around for solution. But I wanted to know why my approach is not working with na.fill. Is it some type of problem with JVM where sparkContext connects or is it something else ?

Comment: I don't think it's a problem or an error because in the API Reference (Scala and python) they explicitly list the accepted types (and DateType is not among them). Why the function was made that way is a complete mystery for me.